# Max conditional expectation of a truncated normal centered at $C>0$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $C>0$. For each $r>0$ define the interval centered at $C$ with radius $r$; that is $I_r:=[C-r,C+r]$. Let $E[X|I_r]$ be the conditional expectation of $X$ on $I_r$. What is the radius $r$ which maximizes $E[X|I_r]$?

My thoughts are that $E[X|I_r]$ has to be a decreasing function of $r$. Increasing $r$ to $r+\epsilon$ should decrease the expected value as there is always more mass in the lower addition $[C-r-\epsilon,C-r]$ than in the upper addition $[C+r,C+r+\epsilon]$.

Im having some difficulties showing this formally, any help on how to think about this?

I also suspect that when $C<0$ then $E[X|I_r]$ is increasing in $r$. Lastly, there seems nothing particularly special about the normal distribution here. For example, if $f$ is the pdf and $f(C-\hat{r}-x)>f(C+\hat{r}+x)$ for all $x\in[0,x']$ then $\max_{x\in [0,x']}E[X|I_{C+\hat{r}+x}]=E[X|I_{C+\hat{r}}]$?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my attempt at an answer

Let $g(r)=E[X|I_r]$, we want to show that this function is decreasing.

$$g'(r)=\frac{(C+r)f(C+r)+(C-r)f(C-r)}{\int_{C-r}^{C+r}f(x)dx}-\frac{f(C-r)+f(C-r)}{\int_{C-r}^{C+r}f(x)dx}g(r)$$

Consider the function, $J(r):=\frac{(C+r)f(C+r)+(C-r)f(C-r)}{f(C-r)+f(C-r)}$, when $X$ is normally distributed and $C>0$ then it is straight forward to show that $J'(r)<0$. For example, when $\sigma=1$ we have $J'(r)=\frac{1 -e^{4Cr}-4Cre^{2Cr}}{(1+e^{2Cr})^2}$

We also know that $g'(r)<0$ in a neighborhood of $0$ as $g$ has a unique max at $r=0$. So if $g'$ is ever positive then there exists a unique minimum $r^*>0$ such that $g'(r^*)=0$. As $g'(r*)=0$ and $J'(r)$ is strictly negative away from 0, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\max_{r\in [r^*-\epsilon,r^*) }J'(r)<\min_{r\in [r^*-\epsilon,r^*)}g'(r)$.

$g(r^*)=g(r)+g'(\zeta_g)\cdot \epsilon$ and $J(r^*)=J(r)+J'(\zeta_J)\cdot \epsilon$. However, $g(r)>J(r)$ and $g'>J'$ so $g(r^*)\neq J(r^*)$.

I had to invoke the normal assumption to show that $J'(r)<0$. I was hoping I would be able to generalize this a bit, to say all densities $f$ such that if $|x|<|y|$ then $f(x)<f(y)$. But Im not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be $r=0$. Because one may prove that if $C>0$, then $\mathbb{E}[X|I_r] \le C$ provided that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, a symmetric distribution around $0$.

Formally speaking, Let $Y \sim X|I_r$ and $f_Y(\cdot)$ be its density. Then we can easily see that $f_Y(C+t) < f_Y(C-t)$ for $t > 0$. Hence
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{C-r}^{C+r} y f_Y(y) \mathrm{d} y = C + \int_{0}^r t[f_Y(C+t) - f_Y(C-t)] \mathrm{d} t \le C.$$

And we may also show that $g(r) = \mathbb{E}[X|I_r]$ is a decreasing function with $g(0) = C$ and $g(\infty) = 0$.

Comment: Its not obvious to me that this follows as if $r_1<r_2$ then you are integrating a over a larger set but you also change the density. Hence, you are also dividing by a larger number. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The decreasing property is just a guess. I am not sure whether it's true or not. The density    $f_Y(y) = c f_X(y)$, for $y \in [C-r, C+r]$, whence we get $\mathbb{E}[Y] \le C$.